# enabling keyboard (arrow up/down) in a list-item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've my mark up as

```
<input id="field" type="text" />
 <ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">one</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">two</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">three</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">four</a></li>
</ul>
```

It's a suggestions list.

When the `#field` is in focus, on pressing arrow up or arrow down, I want to be able to select the items in the list.

So how do I bring the focus to the right item in the list?? I tried something like

```
if (e.keyCode == 40){  //40 for arrow down
     $('.item').first().focus();
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: This will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694179/enabling-keyboard-arrow-up-down-in-a-list-item

Comment: hi @ptamzz, did you got any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no `focus` for `li` or `a`, you have to highlight them by yourself: change the background color of the selected item etc.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work in jquery:

```
$('.item').focusin(function()
{
   $(this).css('background-color',#highlight_color);
});


$('.item').focusout(function()
{
   $(this).css('background-color',#original_color);
});
```